# Run Script after Batch is completed in Photoshop

Tags: batch-processing, photoshop, photoshop-script

Is there a way to run a script AFTER a Batch is completed in Photoshop?

I created an Action that I run it through the Automate > Batch but I would like to run an additional script only AFTER the batch is completed.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to add the script as part of an action. Your action can then be run as a batch process:

Select your action, hit record. Load your script from the file File > Scripts > my_script.jsx (or whatever you've called it). The script will now run. Press STOP, to stop recording the action.

Now, when you run the action as a batch file it will now run as previously but with the addition of my_script.jsx immediately afterwards.

Just make sure your script is error free or it won't record at all. Secondly, don't forget to stop recording the action - or you'll have repercussions.

Comment: That is what I have now but it will not work as per my original question because the script will run at the end of each Action, NOT at the end of the complete batch.

For example if the action is:
1. Resize
2. Change to RGB
3. Run Script

and I have 1000 images, if I run this action as a batch it will run the script 1000 times.

What I want to do is run the Action as a batch and when the Batch is completed THEN run the script.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. In that case, no. The batch file process assumes that you want to perform the same task over and over again, there is no functionality (that I'm aware of) that allows you process something afterwards (as an extra task). You may have to write a script for it - which will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found an answer to this problem, months later working on a different project.

First you need to create a Droplet with the Action(s) you want to run:

File → Automate → Create Droplet

Then you create a Batch file that runs the Droplet:

for %%a in ("C:\Folder\Images_You_Want_Processed*.*") do ( start "" /w "C:\Folder\YourDropletName.exe" "%%a")

In the batch file you can include the order of the actions and run them in order.